# Jquery not triggering on("keydown") in chrome for selectboxes when manually clicking on it

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm using the `on("keydown"` on select boxes to trigger a search field for the eventually very long selectbox.

**Instructions for jsbin:**
  Please *click* into the selectbox, then press a key - no message shows in console in chrome 23.0.1271.64 m

But it fires in firefox etc

It works as well in chrome, but only when using tab to focus the select

See for yourself in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/idatoc/2/edit)

Code is this:

```
    <body>

  <select>
    <option name="aaaa">xaxaxa</option>
    <option name="22">222xaxaxa</option>
    <option name="333">33xaxaxa</option>
  </select>


  <script>

    $("select").on("keydown", function(){
      console.error("keydoooooown");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

how to get the same behaviour in chrome without changing the html markup? e.g. only by changing the javascript part.

Comment: It seems that in Chrome, opening a select box shifts key focus *outside the DOM*, so keypress/up/down events do not trigger their DOM listeners. Instead, keypresses are used solely to interact with the select popup, which does not exist in the DOM.

Comment: @apsillers : how did you figure that one out?

Answer (score -1):

if i see your html you probably want to use it as an action controller you could or use the `.bind` function to atach a event to the dom or for jquery simply use `.keyup`

so perfoming an action would look something like this:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) 
{
        // ESC
        if (e.keyCode == 27)
        {
            $('#closeInteriorDetails').click();
        }

        // Right arrow
        if(e.keyCode == 39)
        {
            $('#nextSlide').click();
        }

        // Left arrow
        if(e.keyCode == 37)
        {
            $('#prevSlide').click();
        }
}
```

Comment: Docs say "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document." http://api.jquery.com/bind/